# XML enum deserialization

Tags: c#, xml, enums, xsd, deserialization

I have a C# enum generated from the following XSD.

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

 <xsd:element name="mails" type="mailsType" />

 <xsd:complexType name="mailsType">
  <xsd:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
   <xsd:element name="mail" type="mailType" />
  </xsd:sequence>
 </xsd:complexType>

 <xsd:complexType name="mailType">
  <xsd:sequence>
   <xsd:element name="envelope" type="envelopeType" />
   <xsd:element name="body" type="bodyType" />
   <xsd:element name="attachment" type="attachmentType"
        minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
  </xsd:sequence>
  <xsd:attribute use="required" name="id" type="xsd:integer" />
 </xsd:complexType>

 <xsd:element name="header">
  <xsd:complexType>
   <xsd:simpleContent>
    <xsd:extension base="xsd:string">
     <xsd:attribute ref="name" use="required" />
    </xsd:extension>
   </xsd:simpleContent>
  </xsd:complexType>
 </xsd:element>

 <xsd:element name="Date" type="xsd:dateTime" />

 <xsd:complexType name="envelopeType">
  <xsd:sequence>
   <xsd:element name="From" type="xsd:string" />
   <xsd:element name="To" type="xsd:string" />
   <xsd:element ref="Date" />
   <xsd:element name="Subject" type="xsd:string" />
   <xsd:element ref="header" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
  </xsd:sequence>
  <xsd:attribute name="From" type="xsd:string" use="required" />
 </xsd:complexType>

 <xsd:simpleType name="bodyType">
  <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string" />
 </xsd:simpleType>

 <xsd:complexType name="attachmentType">
  <xsd:group ref="attachmentContent" />
  <xsd:attribute ref="name" use="required" />
 </xsd:complexType>

 <xsd:group name="attachmentContent">
  <xsd:sequence>
   <xsd:element name="mimetype">
    <xsd:complexType>
     <xsd:attributeGroup ref="mimeTypeAttributes" />
    </xsd:complexType>
   </xsd:element>
   <xsd:element name="content" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
  </xsd:sequence>
 </xsd:group>

 <xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:string" />

 <xsd:attributeGroup name="mimeTypeAttributes">
  <xsd:attribute name="type" type="mimeTopLevelType" use="required" />
  <xsd:attribute name="subtype" type="xsd:string" use="required" />
 </xsd:attributeGroup>

 <xsd:simpleType name="mimeTopLevelType">
  <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
   <xsd:enumeration value="text" />
   <xsd:enumeration value="multipart" />
   <xsd:enumeration value="application" />
   <xsd:enumeration value="message" />
   <xsd:enumeration value="image" />
   <xsd:enumeration value="audio" />
   <xsd:enumeration value="video" />
  </xsd:restriction>
 </xsd:simpleType>

</xsd:schema>
```

I have this C# code:

```
/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.1")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
public enum mimeTopLevelType {

    /// <remarks/>
    text,

    /// <remarks/>
    multipart,

    /// <remarks/>
    application,

    /// <remarks/>
    message,

    /// <remarks/>
    image,

    /// <remarks/>
    audio,

    /// <remarks/>
    video,
}
```

And I have this XML (sketched):

```
<mails>
  <mail id="0">
    ...
    <attachment name="signature.doc">
      <mimetype type="application " subtype="msword"/>
      <content>
    ### removed by spamoracle ###
      </content>
    </attachment>
  </mail>
</mails>
```

When I try to deserialize this XML into a C# object, I get the following error:

> There is an error in XML document (14, 17).

Apparently the problem is that the XML has an element with an attribute "application" and cannot convert that to an enum type.

Is there anyone who can suggest a solution to this problem?

Comment: Do you know https://xsd2code.codeplex.com ?

Comment: I checked it now, but I am creating the c# classes from xsd using .net's built-in xsd command. Does it differ if I use Xsd2Code?

Comment: You should continue in doing so then use the addon from VS to generate the class, it will also generate methods for de-/serializing the objects. In addition to this you will also be able to control the generation of the classes.

Comment: Could you show the offending line 14?

Comment: xsd2Code uses .net's built-in deserializer inside the generated code so it doesnt solve my problem.

Answer (score 2):

And no wonder - you have

```
type="application "
```

instead of

```
type="application"
```

Notice the whitespace at the end of attribute.

Comment: I dont want to change any attribute or elements value.

Comment: @SoyhanBeyazıt - then you are out of luck - xml document where attribute is set to type="application " is not valid according to xsd you've declared. If you want to parse this kind of screwed up documents, you have to do it manually or redeclare mimeTopLevelType to be just string (no restriction).